# Imperfect Substitutes and Utility Funcitions

Tags: microeconomics, utility, consumer-theory

The utility function for perfect substitutes is defined as U(X,Y) = aX + bY. If the two goods X&Y are imperfect substitutes what would be their utility function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, any utility function that produces non-linear and downward sloping indifference curves will feature imperfect substitutability between goods. (By considering only *goods*, we're implicitly assuming "more is preferred to less", or positive marginal utility, for each good.) In other words, look at the marginal rate of substitution and see if it depends on the quantity of either good; if it does, then there is imperfect substitutability.

## Examples

- Quasi-linear utility: $u(x,y)=v(x)+y$, where $v(x)$ is non-linear in $x$ (e.g. $v(x)=\sqrt x$)
- Additively separable utility: $u(x,y)=g(x)+h(y)$, where $g,h$ are non-linear functions
- Cobb-Douglas: $u(x,y)=x^\alpha y^\beta$, where $\alpha,\beta$ are constants
- <s>Leontief (perfect complement): $\style{text-decoration:line-through}{u(x,y)=\min\{\alpha x,\beta y\}}$</s> [Leontief utility function features *non*substitutability rather than imperfect substitutability.]
- CES utility: $u(x,y)=\left(\alpha x^\rho+\beta y^\rho\right)^{1/\rho}$, where $\rho\ne1$. Note that the class of CES utility functions includes Cobb-Douglas (as $\rho\to0$), Leontief (as $\rho\to-\infty$), and linear utility (as $\rho=1$) as special cases.

This [lecture note](http://www.econ.ucla.edu/sboard/teaching/econ11_09/econ11_09_lecture2.pdf#page=15) by Simon Board has examples and indifference curves corresponding to the cases above.

Comment: Leontief utilities represent imperfect substitution? Not non-substitution?

Comment: Similary, I don't think that if $U(x,y) = x -y $ then goods $x$ and $y$ are substitutes. Having a negative slope for the indifference curve seems like a logical think to want.

Comment: @denesp: Thanks. Your point on Leontief utility is well taken. I've also added an explanation making clear that we're considering only *goods* here, which would rule out the case of negative marginal utility.

Answer (score 0):

Cobb-Douglas utility does NOT reflect substitute goods. They are unrelated. The demand equations are $x_i=\frac{a_i \cdot m}{p_i}$ for each good $i$. Note that only $p_i$ affects the demand for $x_i$; other goods' prices don't enter into demand. Thus, all other goods are unrelated: neither substitutes nor complements.